# Flex Datagrid sort date field without knowing the fieldname

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, date, apache-flex, datagrid

Need to sort a date column in Flex datagrid. The sort function for flex gives entire row data as parameter and comparison has to be done using the property having date .i.e. data1.datefield and data2.datefield2. Currently i only have field name as text, how can i use it in comparison?

Comment: if you have the field as a string you can access it like this object[propertyName] , you can also check the Object.hasOwnProperty (could be useful)

Comment: check out this similar question about sorting on dates in data grids  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892409/sort-dates-in-a-flash-as3-datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called compare function created as below

```
function(obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int{return date_sortCompareFunc(obj1, obj2, this.name);};
```

and used column name as suggested by @simion314